# How can I simplify my conditional formatting

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, logic, conditional-formatting

My spreadsheet has over 30 conditional formatting rules and I was wondering if I could combine them.

[image]

I've attached the picture to give an idea but basically, the user can set/change the cancelation policies on the right (BC9:BF18) by setting a start/end date and selecting a policy.

I then use conditional formatting to color the calendar using this info (each cell of the calendar is set to its actual date, so the blue June 1 cell actually contains `01/June/2021` but is formatted to just show `1`). For each row of the BC9:BF18 table, I have the following rules (eg. for first row [9]):

```
=AND(E9>=$BC$9,E9<=$BE$9,$BF$9="High") - Change to blue
=AND(E9>=$BC$9,E9<=$BE$9,$BF$9="Standard") - Change to white
=AND(E9>=$BC$9,E9<=$BE$9,$BF$9="Peak") - Change to red
=AND(E9>=$BC$9,E9<=$BE$9,$BF$9) - Change to a set color
```

That's 4 rules for each of the 10 lines (BC9:BC18), so 40 different conditional formats.

I'd now like to add to that that if the day is a holiday (holiday dates will be in a table below, let's say BC30:BC60) then make the font red but keep the background color in line with the cancelation policy.

This will require loads and loads more conditional formatting rules which would need to go above all the old rules eg. `=AND(E9>=$BC$9,E9<=$BE$9,$BF$9="High",[OR(E9=$BC$30, E9=$BC$31....)] - Change to blue with red font`, Can anyone see a way to simplify this?

I have a few suggestions but I'm not sure if they'll work:

(a) Changing the order so that the end date doesn't matter, the next formula will overwrite on its start date

(b) Checking all policies that match 'High' (so if(BF9:BF18='High'... somehow get that start/end date etc.

(c) for the new bit (checking if the date is in table BC30:BC60) there must be an easier way than checking if the date matches BC30 then BC31 then BC32 `=OR(E9=$BC$30,E9=$BC$31,E9=$BC$32, etc.

Comment: Why you don't add a conditional formatting if any day & Month name match with your holiday table, then red front. So you don't have to adjust all your code all over again?

Comment: Yeah but that would overrule the background colour change, so you'd be able to see that it was a holiday but you wouldn't be able to see which cancellation policy was being used.

Comment: Ya, too bad it will overwrite. It will be better to write app scrip to formulate the font color, is it part of your consideration?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before using app-script to change the border colour of every cell that matches a holiday date, it was a lot of coding tho as it needed to find the cell reference of every date that matched a holiday date and then loop through and change the borders. The problem is I want to show each of these calendars on separate monthly sheets so I'd need to run all that script on each page!

Comment: You only need eight total rules. Share a link to a copy of your spreadsheet, being sure to set the link's Share permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." Then comment below that you've done this, and I'll try to circle back around and share them on the spreadsheet in a duplicate sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HnHVvb2aM9Zkk6TwIuy3ppN6-xvEmWT5i-aL1-qMOLw/edit?usp=sharing done @ErikTyler

Comment: Seeing your spreadsheet, I did not understand your post clearly. I understood you to be saying that you were trying to consolidate rules for formatting the BC9:BF18 range, and that you were trying to pair four existing rules with two conditions (non-holiday or holiday), which would have been eight rules. In actuality, it seems what you want to do is to take every data in all calendars for all years, find the BC9:BF18 range where each date fits, mirror the formatting of that BC9:CF18 range and then include red text for holidays.

Comment: I see inefficiencies in just about every formula in the sheet. But the CF rules alone would have to account for all underlying states for 10 rows plus three additional transient states for those rows, and then for the holiday state. Again, I did not understand your post to be saying this. Creating all the necessary rules correctly would require an expert and several hours of time. While the above can be accomplished, it is far beyond the scope of what a free forum run by volunteers can provide.

Comment: So the best way to do it is the way that I've done it I guess. I've thought of a few ways I can make it more efficient, also, the CF for the underlying state and three transient states are already done, that's 40 of the 50 necessary CF rules working. I wasn't asking for somebody to spend hours doing it for me, just if anyone had ideas of how to make it more efficient. Thanks for looking over it and getting back to me :)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid your option "c" you can use the [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function. Create a conditional rule which applies to all the ranges where you want the font color to be red  if holiday.

#### Example:

Suppose your holiday list is in range `A2:A` and the date you are checking is in `C2` then the custom conditional formula would be:

> `=match(C2, A1:A)`